# How to Simulate Data Entry in an Input Field and Trigger a Button Click Using Scrapy Instead of Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

Having worked with Selenium, I'm in the process of transitioning my project to Scrapy, but I've encountered some challenges. I've explored the documentation, but I haven't found a solution yet.

```
input_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "location-typeahead-home-input")
input_element.send_keys("Boston Park Plaza")
time.sleep(2)

button_xpath = "//main[@id='main-content']//button"
button_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, button_xpath)
if len(button_elements) >= 2:
    second_button = button_elements[1]
    second_button.click()
else:
    button_elements[0].click()`
```

I've experimented with the sample code, but it seems to require a form, which is not available in this context.

```
input_element = response.css("input#location-typeahead-home-input")
input_element_value = "Boston Park Plaza"

button = response.xpath("//main[@id='main-content']//button")

yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formdata={input_element.attrib['name']: input_element_value},
    formname=None,
    clickdata={'xpath': "//main[@id='main-content']//button"},
    callback=self.after_search
)`
```

I've attempted to transition my Selenium project to Scrapy and encountered issues with input field interactions and button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is: You can't press buttons using Scrapy!

You need to understand how data is being sent to the server (i.e., POST method) and then you have to narrate things just as the browser does.

Comment: but what if the request is on the server side how can you get that?

Comment: Selenium requires GUI elements, if your server is CLI, you won't be able to run it. May be if you can provide specific details, we may assist accordingly.

Comment: I want to set a location for Uber Eats, but I'm struggling to capture the request that sets the location and receives the response. If you could assist me in obtaining that specific request, or if there's a Scrappy-related method to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a simple thing actually. Target website uses cookies to tracking everything and it's interacting with multiple 3rd party APIs to identify yours as well as well target location and once it know the location. You need to load the website and get cookies, and call 3rd party APIs using the collected cookie and then use the newly cookie generated by last API call.